# 2 MySQL versions running on port 3306

Tags: mysql

I have MAMP PRO 5.5 on my macOS 10.14 which uses MySQL on port 3306.

I just installed MySQL via brew for a flask tutorial for which I did `brew install mysql`. All went well.

Now I thought that if I start MAMP PRO, it would complain that port 3306 is already in use.

But it didn't !

```
mysql --version
mysql  Ver 8.0.18 for osx10.14 on x86_64 (Homebrew)
```

And in mysql :

```
mysql> SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'PORT';
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| port          | 3306  |
+---------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

And when I go to phpMyAdmin in MAMP PRO it's showing all of my PHP based MySQL databases. This also is using port 3306 ?

```
$pwd
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin
$ ./mysql --user=root -p
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 72
Server version: 5.7.26 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2019, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'PORT';
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| port          | 0     |
+---------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

How is this possible ?

EDIT : I did `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'PORT';` in MAMP's MySQL and its showing 0. But phpMyAdmin is showing the right databases for MAMP.

Not sure what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this behaviour is sample. One of the servers have communication with client via TCP port. In your case this is 3306. And you will find in to the config of this MySQL server records like:

```
[client]
port = 3306

[mysqld]
port - 3306
```

From command line you can access it with command like:

```
mysql -P 3306 ...
```

The MAMP use socket. This is special file in your filesystem and only software which run on your machine can access it. The config of MySQL server will look like:

```
[mysqld]
socket=/path/to/socket

[client]
socket=/path/to/socket
```

and you can connect to this instance with command:

```
mysql --socket /path/to/socket ....
```